# Probability of "Not A or Not B" when events are independent

Tags: probability, independence

Let's say $P(A) = .5$ and $P(B) = .2$ and they are independent events. What would $P(A^{c}\cup B^{c})$ be?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:$$P(A^{c}\cup B^{c})= P((A\cap B)^{c})= 1- P(A\cap B)= 1- P(A)P(B)=...$$

Comment: I came up with .9 as the answer, would that be correct?

Comment: That is perfectly fine.......